# Caret model with custom cost function

Tags: r, r-caret

I want to train an Elastic Net classifier with a case-weighted error function. The function needs to accept an extra argument `weights` that allows different observations to carry different weights when calculating performance error. Is this possible to do in Caret?

```
# Weighted RMSE function with weights argument.
weighted_rmse <- function(prediction, target, weights) {
  sum(abs(prediction - target)) * weights
}

# Example data.
trainX <- iris[1:100, 1:4]
trainOutcome <- as.numeric(iris$Species[1:100])

fit <- train(
  x = trainX, y = trainOutcome,
  method = "glmnet",
  trControl = trainControl(
    method = "loocv",
    selectionFunction = "oneSE",
    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary # <- replace with something like weighted_rsme()
  )
)
```

Comment: `caret::train` has an `...` argument that is "passed on to the classification or regression routine". `glmnet::glmnet` takes an argument `weights`, so you should be able to specify `weights = my_weights`, where `my_weights` are your training data weights.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you @GregorThomas